# What does transpose(3, 0, 1, 2) mean?

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

What does this mean?

```
data.transpose(3, 0, 1, 2)
```

---

Also, if `data.shape == (10, 10, 10)`, why do I get `ValueError: axes don't match array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the python documentation on [np.transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), the second argument of the `np.transpose` function is `axes`, which is a *list of ints, optional
        by default and **reverse the dimensions, otherwise permute the axes
        according to the values given***.

Example :

```
>>> x = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

>>> np.transpose(x, (0,1))
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

>>> np.transpose(x, (1,0))
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks, So if my data is (3,3,3,2) what is data.transpose(3, 0, 1, 2) means?

Comment: There is no mention of the actual problem... (3.0.1.2)

Comment: Hey @Jarvis All I meant was that the question had 2 parts; your answer just **hinted** at one of them. I tried to provide another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62975651/9625777). The purpose of downvoting was just to improve the quality of answers the question may receive. The author has accepted your answer but this doesn't shroud the fact that your answer hardly has any upvotes. Please be humble next time. Let's make it a better community :)

Answer (score 5):

Let me discuss in terms of Python3.

> I use the transpose function in python as `data.transpose(3, 0, 1, 2)`

This is wrong as this operation requires 4 dimensions, while you only provide 3 (as in `(10,10,10)`). Reproducible as:

```
>>> a = np.arange(60).reshape((1,4,5,3))
>>> b = a.transpose((2,0,1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

You can either add another dimension simply by reshaping (10,10,10) to (1,10,10,10) if the image batch is 1. This can be done as:

```py
w,h,c = original_image.shape #10,10,10
modified_img = np.reshape((1,w,h,c)) #(1,10,10,10)
```

> what does it mean of 3, 0, 1, 2.

For 2D numpy arrays, `transpose` for an array (matrix) operates just as the names say. But for higher dimensional arrays like yours, it basically works as `moveaxis`.

```
>>> a = np.arange(60).reshape((4,5,3))
>>> b = a.transpose((2,0,1))
>>> b.shape
(3, 4, 5)
>>> c = np.moveaxis(a,-1,0)
>>> c.shape
(3, 4, 5)
>>> b
array([[[ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
        [15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
        [30, 33, 36, 39, 42],
        [45, 48, 51, 54, 57]],

       [[ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13],
        [16, 19, 22, 25, 28],
        [31, 34, 37, 40, 43],
        [46, 49, 52, 55, 58]],

       [[ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14],
        [17, 20, 23, 26, 29],
        [32, 35, 38, 41, 44],
        [47, 50, 53, 56, 59]]])
>>> c
array([[[ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
        [15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
        [30, 33, 36, 39, 42],
        [45, 48, 51, 54, 57]],

       [[ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13],
        [16, 19, 22, 25, 28],
        [31, 34, 37, 40, 43],
        [46, 49, 52, 55, 58]],

       [[ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14],
        [17, 20, 23, 26, 29],
        [32, 35, 38, 41, 44],
        [47, 50, 53, 56, 59]]])
```

As evident, both methods work the same.

Answer (score 4):

The operation converts from (`samples`, `rows`, `columns`, `channels`) into (`samples`, `channels`, `rows`, `cols`),maybe opencv to pytorch.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `np.zeros((0, 1, 2, 3)).transpose(3, 0, 1, 2).shape` is actually equal to `(3, 0, 1, 2)`.

Comment: Since the transpose is (3,0,1,2), shouldn't it be converting from (samples, rows, cols, channels) into (channels, samples, rows, cols)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [numpy.transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

> Use transpose(a, argsort(axes)) to invert the transposition of tensors
>   when using the axes keyword argument.
>
> Transposing a 1-D array returns an unchanged view of the original
>   array.

---

e.g.

```
>>> x = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
>>> x
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>>
>>> np.transpose(x)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You specified too many values in the transpose

```
>>> a = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
>>> a.shape (2, 2, 2)
>>> a.transpose([2,0,1])
array([[[0, 2],
        [4, 6]],

       [[1, 3],
        [5, 7]]])
>>> a.transpose(3,0,1,2) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module> ValueError: axes don't match array
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you have taken a 3 dimensional matrix and applied a 4 dimensional transpose.
your command is to convert a 4d matrix(batch,rows,cols,channel) to another 4d matrix (rows,cols,channel,batch) but you need a command to convert 3d matrix.so remove 3 and write
`data.transpose(2, 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

For all `i, j, k, l`, the following holds true:

```
arr[i, j, k, l] == arr.transpose(3, 0, 1, 2)[l, i, j, k]
```

---

[`transpose(3, 0, 1, 2)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) reorders the array dimensions from `(a, b, c, d)` to `(d, a, b, c)`:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros((10, 11, 12, 13))

>>> arr.transpose(3, 0, 1, 2).shape
(13, 10, 11, 12)
```